# Como procedemos vs como procederemos

Tags: português-brasileiro, conjugações

A minha intenção é formular uma pergunta sobre como eu e outras pessoas devemos agir. Em outras palavras, dada uma situação `X` o que eu e meus colegas devemos fazer?

Usando o verbo `proceder`, qual das duas formas é a correta?

Como procedemos?

OU

Como procederemos?

Comment: Eu não usaria nem uma forma e nem outra.  Sei que não estou esclarecendo sua dúvida a respeito do verbo proceder, mas eu diria "o que vamos fazer?", "como vamos agir?", "como proceder neste caso?", ou até mesmo, "como vamos proceder?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As duas são corretas. A primeira forma é no presente a segunda no futuro.

Acho que o que precisas, neste caso, é do infinitivo pessoal:

> Como procedermos?

Ou em alternativa usar o infinitivo do verbo:

> Como proceder?

[Conjugação do verbo proceder](https://conjuga-me.net/verbo-proceder)

Comment: Nah, o infinitivo pessoal soa-me mal. Aliás, na conjugação tem lá o para: "para procedermos". Um exemplo em que o infinitivo pessoal funciona: "Como achas que temos de fazer para procedermos?" Mas neste caso acho que não pode ser usado.

Comment: @ANeves a mim soa-me bem. Mas posso estar enganado.

Answer (score 1):

Entre as duas, o mais correto seria "procedemos". "Como procedemos?" seria equivalente a "O que fazemos agora/Como agimos agora/Que passos devemos tomar?".

Não acredito que alguém use o termo "procederemos" nesse contexto. Entre as duas, o mais comum e *natural* seria sempre utilizar o verbo no presente - "procedemos" - ainda que, gramaticalmente, ambas as frases estejam corretas.

Existe ainda a possibilidade de usar  o infinitivo impessoal ("Como proceder?"), se, por exemplo, se se está a relatar o momento em que essa dúvida surgiu a terceiros:

> Portanto, perante `X`, surgiu a dúvida: "Como proceder?". Depois de avaliarmos as opções, optamos por fazer `Y`.

No entanto, no meio de um diálogo, utilizar-se-ia:

> O colega `Y` depara-se com este problema e pergunta aos restantes colegas: "Como procedemos?".

pois o objetivo do colega seria obter uma resposta do grupo e estabelecer uma estratégia naquele instante.